# GCP Cloud Storage - Golang aws sdk2 - Upload file with s3 INTEROPERABILITY Creds

Tags: go, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to implements download/upload a file from/to a bucket in cloud storage via the s3 go sdk [aws-sdk-go-v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2) using the [Interoperability feature](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability)

The download is working as expected, but the upload isnt working, with this error message: `SDK 2022/09/14 11:24:43 DEBUG request failed with unretryable error https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: , HostID: , api error SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.`

As I use same access_key and secret_key for both download and upload, it does not seems to be a credentials problem.
Plus, the service account behind the hmac keys has the Storage object Admin Role.

Here the code:

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/s3/manager"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
)

var BUCKET_NAME = ""

func main() {

    //prepare gcp resolver
    gcpResolver := aws.EndpointResolverWithOptionsFunc(func(service, region string, options ...interface{}) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
        return aws.Endpoint{
            URL:               "https://storage.googleapis.com",
            SigningRegion:     "auto",
            Source:            aws.EndpointSourceCustom,
            HostnameImmutable: true,
        }, nil
    })
    //file with fornat : $accessKey:$secretKey
    file, _ := os.ReadFile("/home/bapt/creds/amz-keys-gcp-2")
    keys := strings.Split(string(file), ":")

    //init the config options
    optConfig := []func(*config.LoadOptions) error{
        config.WithRegion("auto"),
        config.WithCredentialsProvider(credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider(keys[0], strings.TrimRight(keys[1], "\n"), "")),
        config.WithClientLogMode(aws.LogRetries | aws.LogRequestWithBody | aws.LogResponseWithBody | aws.LogRequestEventMessage | aws.LogResponseEventMessage | aws.LogSigning),
        config.WithEndpointResolverWithOptions(gcpResolver),
    }

    //init config
    cfg, _ := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), optConfig...)

    //init service
    svc := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
    tempFile, _ := os.CreateTemp("/tmp", "test-gcp-*")
    defer tempFile.Close()
    downloader := manager.NewDownloader(svc)
    downloader.Download(context.TODO(),tempFile, &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(BUCKET_NAME),
        Key:    aws.String("file-test.txt"),
    })
    //init uploader ( no multipart)
    uploader := manager.NewUploader(svc, func(u *manager.Uploader) {
        u.Concurrency = 1
        u.MaxUploadParts = 1
    })
    //upload
    _, err := uploader.Upload(context.TODO(), &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(BUCKET_NAME),
        Key:    aws.String("file-test.txt"),
        Body:   strings.NewReader("HELLO"),
    })
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

go.mod

```
module gcps3/v2

go 1.18

require (
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2 v1.16.14
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config v1.17.5
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials v1.12.18
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/s3/manager v1.11.31
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3 v1.27.9
)

require (
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/protocol/eventstream v1.4.7 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/ec2/imds v1.12.15 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/internal/configsources v1.1.21 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/internal/endpoints/v2 v2.4.15 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/internal/ini v1.3.22 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/internal/v4a v1.0.12 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/internal/accept-encoding v1.9.8 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/internal/checksum v1.1.16 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/internal/presigned-url v1.9.15 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/internal/s3shared v1.13.15 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sso v1.11.21 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ssooidc v1.13.3 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sts v1.16.17 // indirect
    github.com/aws/smithy-go v1.13.2 // indirect
    github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath v0.4.0 // indirect
)
```

And here the debug trace of the PUT ( my bucket name is replaced by **BUCKET**, and access_key with **GOOG1ID**:

```
SDK 2022/09/14 14:52:37 DEBUG Request Signature:
---[ CANONICAL STRING  ]-----------------------------
PUT
/BUCKET/file-test.txt
x-id=PutObject
accept-encoding:identity
amz-sdk-invocation-id:d6776820-e336-4bdf-afa3-0ca3b6d5b0a0
amz-sdk-request:attempt=1; max=3
content-length:5
content-type:application/octet-stream
host:storage.googleapis.com
x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date:20220914T125237Z

accept-encoding;amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
---[ STRING TO SIGN ]--------------------------------
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20220914T125237Z
20220914/auto/s3/aws4_request
bc09.....daf520
-----------------------------------------------------
SDK 2022/09/14 14:52:37 DEBUG Request
PUT /BUCKET/file-test.txt?x-id=PutObject HTTP/1.1
Host: storage.googleapis.com
User-Agent: aws-sdk-go-v2/1.16.14 os/linux lang/go/1.18.1 md/GOOS/linux md/GOARCH/amd64 api/s3/1.27.9 ft/s3-transfer
Content-Length: 5
Accept-Encoding: identity
Amz-Sdk-Invocation-Id: d6776820-e336-4bdf-afa3-0ca3b6d5b0a0
Amz-Sdk-Request: attempt=1; max=3
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=GOOG1ID/20220914/auto/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept-encoding;amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=c994....37d0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
X-Amz-Content-Sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
X-Amz-Date: 20220914T125237Z

HELLO
SDK 2022/09/14 14:52:37 DEBUG Response
HTTP/2.0 403 Forbidden
Content-Length: 883
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 14 Sep 2022 12:52:38 GMT
Server: UploadServer
X-Guploader-Uploadid: ADPycdt0aCu6BTmzWQl2Ehc4q2sP8rtexDb4Keyn6cQL_GigREvc8T1CzX0HH-ZXgw_6XWLJPPYXufwRCr0Sl7uSsiIi0Q

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20220914T125237Z
20220914/auto/s3/aws4_request
0a10....d63e</StringToSign><CanonicalRequest>PUT
/BUCKET/file-test.txt
x-id=PutObject
accept-encoding:identity,gzip(gfe)
amz-sdk-invocation-id:d6776820-e336-4bdf-afa3-0ca3b6d5b0a0
amz-sdk-request:attempt=1; max=3
content-length:5
content-type:application/octet-stream
host:storage.googleapis.com
x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date:20220914T125237Z

accept-encoding;amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest></Error>
SDK 2022/09/14 14:52:37 DEBUG request failed with unretryable error https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: , HostID: , api error SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
operation error S3: PutObject, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: , HostID: , api error SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
```

I tested the upload, with this python script, and it works (same creds)

```
boto3.set_stream_logger('', logging.DEBUG)
GCP_BUCKET = True
FILE_TO_BE_UPLOADED = '/tmp/toto'

if GCP_BUCKET:
    ACCESS_KEY = "ACESS"
    SECRET_KEY = "SECRET"
    bucket_name = "BUCKET"    
    region_name="auto"
    endpoint_url="https://storage.googleapis.com"
    
def makeS3Client():
    s3 = boto3.client("s3", 
                region_name=region_name,
                endpoint_url=endpoint_url,
                aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
                )

    return s3


def upload_file(s3,bucket_name,fname):
    """
    Uploads file to S3 bucket using S3 client object
    :return: None
    """
    object_name = os.path.basename(fname)
    file_name = os.path.abspath(fname)
    #file_name = os.path.join(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve(), fname)

    response = s3.upload_file(file_name, bucket_name, object_name)
    #print(response)  # prints None
```

The only different between go and python i saw in the https requests made is the signedHeaders used.

But the go code with an s3 aws bucket is working fine...

Am I missing an option ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 100% certain the key in the file is in the required format and does not contain another `:`?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen yes 100% certain, as the download passed successfully with the same client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue that @h3yduck mentioned, it seems that accept-encoding needs to be excluded from the signature signing process in the v2 library. Since the signature is dependent on the headers mentioned in SignedHeaders, we will have to recalculate the signature ourselves.

The AWS Configuration object exposes a variable for a custom http client to be used for all services. We can use this by defining our own RoundTripper that modifies the request's signature to one that doesn't account for accept-encoding.

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    v4 "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/signer/v4"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/s3/manager"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
)

var BUCKET_NAME = "test"

type RecalculateV4Signature struct {
    next   http.RoundTripper
    signer *v4.Signer
    cfg    aws.Config
}

func (lt *RecalculateV4Signature) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    // store for later use
    val := req.Header.Get("Accept-Encoding")

    // delete the header so the header doesn't account for in the signature
    req.Header.Del("Accept-Encoding")

    // sign with the same date
    timeString := req.Header.Get("X-Amz-Date")
    timeDate, _ := time.Parse("20060102T150405Z", timeString)

    creds, _ := lt.cfg.Credentials.Retrieve(req.Context())
    err := lt.signer.SignHTTP(req.Context(), creds, req, v4.GetPayloadHash(req.Context()), "s3", lt.cfg.Region, timeDate)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // Reset Accept-Encoding if desired
    req.Header.Set("Accept-Encoding", val)

    fmt.Println("AfterAdjustment")
    rrr, _ := httputil.DumpRequest(req, false)
    fmt.Println(string(rrr))

    // follows up the original round tripper
    return lt.next.RoundTrip(req)
}

func main() {

    //prepare gcp resolver
    gcpResolver := aws.EndpointResolverWithOptionsFunc(func(service, region string, options ...interface{}) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
        return aws.Endpoint{
            URL:               "https://storage.googleapis.com",
            SigningRegion:     "auto",
            Source:            aws.EndpointSourceCustom,
            HostnameImmutable: true,
        }, nil
    })
    //file with format : $accessKey:$secretKey

    //init the config options
    optConfig := []func(*config.LoadOptions) error{
        config.WithRegion("auto"),
        config.WithCredentialsProvider(credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider("test", "test", "session")),
        config.WithClientLogMode(aws.LogRetries | aws.LogRequestWithBody | aws.LogResponseWithBody | aws.LogRequestEventMessage | aws.LogResponseEventMessage | aws.LogSigning),
        config.WithEndpointResolverWithOptions(gcpResolver),
    }

    //init config
    cfg, _ := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), optConfig...)
    // Assign custom client with our own transport
    cfg.HTTPClient = &http.Client{Transport: &RecalculateV4Signature{http.DefaultTransport, v4.NewSigner(), cfg}}
    //init service
    svc := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
    uploader := manager.NewUploader(svc, func(u *manager.Uploader) {
        u.Concurrency = 1
        u.MaxUploadParts = 1
    })
    //upload
    _, err := uploader.Upload(context.TODO(), &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(BUCKET_NAME),
        Key:    aws.String("file-test.txt"),
        Body:   strings.NewReader("HELLO"),
    })
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

P.S. the client should ideally be built on BuildableClient from aws as they provide sensible defaults for their services, I will leave that up to the reader

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/issues/1816 the v2 SDK doesn't support GCP GCS.

Removing `Accept-Encoding` from the sighed headers solved the issue for me, but I'm not sure if it's an advised thing to do. Also, I didn't find a way to remove this header from the list of signed headers *(there might be a middleware that supports this)*, other than modifying the lib's source code *(adding it to the `IgnoredHeaders` global variable)*.

Comment: Using [middleware](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/middleware/) is a more natural way to fix this issue. You should plug a middleware that removes the header from the request into the `Finalize` step before the `Signing` middleware and another middleware that restores the header after that `Signing` middleware.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@szrg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73717477/gcp-cloud-storage-golang-aws-sdk2-upload-file-with-s3-interoperability-creds/74382598#comment134215661_74378276), this can be solved by using the [middleware](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/middleware/) framework provided by the AWS Go SDK v2. We add middleware to remove the offending header before the request is signed and then replace the header after signing.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    v4 "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/signer/v4"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/smithy-go/middleware"
    smithyhttp "github.com/aws/smithy-go/transport/http"
)

const acceptEncodingHeader = "Accept-Encoding"

type acceptEncodingKey struct{}

func GetAcceptEncodingKey(ctx context.Context) (v string) {
    v, _ = middleware.GetStackValue(ctx, acceptEncodingKey{}).(string)
    return v
}

func SetAcceptEncodingKey(ctx context.Context, value string) context.Context {
    return middleware.WithStackValue(ctx, acceptEncodingKey{}, value)
}

var dropAcceptEncodingHeader = middleware.FinalizeMiddlewareFunc("DropAcceptEncodingHeader",
    func(ctx context.Context, in middleware.FinalizeInput, next middleware.FinalizeHandler) (out middleware.FinalizeOutput, metadata middleware.Metadata, err error) {
        req, ok := in.Request.(*smithyhttp.Request)
        if !ok {
            return out, metadata, &v4.SigningError{Err: fmt.Errorf("unexpected request middleware type %T", in.Request)}
        }

        ae := req.Header.Get(acceptEncodingHeader)
        ctx = SetAcceptEncodingKey(ctx, ae)
        req.Header.Del(acceptEncodingHeader)
        in.Request = req

        return next.HandleFinalize(ctx, in)
    },
)

var replaceAcceptEncodingHeader = middleware.FinalizeMiddlewareFunc("ReplaceAcceptEncodingHeader",
    func(ctx context.Context, in middleware.FinalizeInput, next middleware.FinalizeHandler) (out middleware.FinalizeOutput, metadata middleware.Metadata, err error) {
        req, ok := in.Request.(*smithyhttp.Request)
        if !ok {
            return out, metadata, &v4.SigningError{Err: fmt.Errorf("unexpected request middleware type %T", in.Request)}
        }

        ae := GetAcceptEncodingKey(ctx)
        req.Header.Set(acceptEncodingHeader, ae)
        in.Request = req

        return next.HandleFinalize(ctx, in)
    },
)

func SignForGCP(o *s3.Options) {
    o.APIOptions = append(o.APIOptions, func(stack *middleware.Stack) error {
        if err := stack.Finalize.Insert(dropAcceptEncodingHeader, "Signing", middleware.Before); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if err := stack.Finalize.Insert(replaceAcceptEncodingHeader, "Signing", middleware.After); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        return nil
    })
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    accessKey := os.Getenv("GCP_ACCESS_KEY")
    secretKey := os.Getenv("GCP_SECRET_KEY")
    bucket := os.Getenv("GCP_STORAGE_BUCKET")
    endpoint := "https://storage.googleapis.com"

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx,
        config.WithCredentialsProvider(credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider{
            Value: aws.Credentials{
                AccessKeyID:     accessKey,
                SecretAccessKey: secretKey,
            },
        }),
        config.WithRegion("auto"),
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Printf("failed to load configuration: %s", err.Error()))
        return
    }

    client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg,
        s3.WithEndpointResolver(s3.EndpointResolverFromURL(endpoint)),
        SignForGCP,
    )

    res, err := client.ListObjectsV2(ctx, &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket:  &bucket,
        MaxKeys: 10,
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Printf("failed to list items: %s", err.Error()))
        return
    }

    for _, o := range res.Contents {
        fmt.Println(">>> ", *o.Key)
    }
}
```